# How can I implement it using DiffSuppressFunc()?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: I'm developing a TF Provider.

There's an attribute `foo` of type `string` in one of my resources. Different representations of values of `foo` can map to the same *normalized* version but only backend can return a normalized version of value of `foo`.

When implementing the resources, I was thinking I could store any user value for `foo` (i.e., it's not necessarily normalized). And then I could leverage [DiffSuppressFunc](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/schemas/schema-behaviors) to detect any potential differences. For example, main.tf stores any user input (by definition), TF state could store either normalized version return from a backend or user input version (don't matter a lot). And then, the biggest challenge is to differentiate between structural update (requires an update) and syntactic update (doesn't require update since it can be converted to the same normalized version).

In order to implement this I could use

```
"foo": {
...
DiffSuppressFunc: func(k, old, new string, d *schema.ResourceData) bool {
    // Option #1
    normalizedOld := network.GetNormalized(old)
    normalizedNew := network.GetNormalized(new)
    return normalizedOld == normalizedNew

    // Option #2
    // Backend also supports a check whether such a value exists already 
    // and returns such a object
    if obj, ok := network.Exists(new); ok { return obj.Id == d.GetObjId(); }
}
}
```

However it seems like I can't send network requests in DiffSuppressFunc since it doesn't accept `meta interface{}` from:

```
func resourceCreate(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{})
```

So I can't access my specific http client (even though I could send some generic network request).

Is there a smart way to avoid this limitation to pass `meta interface{}` to DiffSuppressFunc:

```
    // The interface{} parameter is the result of the Provider type
    // ConfigureFunc field execution. If the Provider does not define
    // a ConfigureFunc, this will be nil. This parameter is conventionally
    // used to store API clients and other provider instance specific data.
    //
    // The diagnostics return parameter, if not nil, can contain any
    // combination and multiple of warning and/or error diagnostics.
    ReadContext ReadContextFunc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intention for `DiffSuppressFunc` is that it be only syntactic normalization that doesn't rely on information from outside of the provider. A `DiffSuppressFunc` should not typically interact with anything outside of the provider because the SDK can call it at various steps and expects it to return a consistent result each time, rather than varying based on the state of the remote system.

If you need to rely on information from the remote system then you'll need to implement the logic you're discussing in [the `CustomizeDiff` function](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/customizing-differences) instead. That function is the lowest level of abstraction for diff customization in the SDK but in return for the low level of abstraction it also allows more flexibility than the higher-level built-in behaviors in the SDK.

In the `CustomizeDiff` function you will have access to `meta` and so you can make API requests if you need to.

Inside your `CustomizeDiff` function you can use `d.GetChange` to obtain both the previous value and the new value from the configuration to use in the same way as the `old` and `new` arguments to `DiffSuppressFunc`.

You can then use `d.SetNew` to change the planned value for a particular attribute based on what you learned. To approximate what `DiffSuppressFunc` would do you would call `d.SetNew` with the value from the *prior state* -- the "old" value.

When implementing `CustomizeDiff` you must respect the consistency rules that apply to all Terraform providers, which include:

- When planning initial creation of an object, if the module author provided a specific value in the configuration then you must preserve exactly that value, without normalization.
- When planning an update to an existing object, if the module author has provided a specific value in the configuration then you must return either the exact value they wrote without normalization *or* return exactly the value from the prior state to indicate that the new configuration value is functionally equivalent to the previous value.

When implementing `Read` there is also a similar consistency rule:

- If the value you read from the remote system is not equal to what was in the prior state but the new value is functionally equivalent to the prior state then you must return the value from the prior state to preserve the way the author originally wrote it, rather than the way the remote system normalized it.

All of these rules exist to help ensure that a particular Terraform configuration can *converge*, which is to say that after running `terraform apply` it should be possible to immediately run `terraform plan` and see it report "No changes". If you don't stick to these rules then Terraform may return an explicit error (for problems it's able to detect) or it may just behave strangely due to the provider producing confusing information that doesn't match the assumptions of the protocol.

Comment: That looks great! I've got a follow up: is there a way to access `d *schema.ResourceData` somehow?

Comment: Namely, it looks like I need value of other resource attributes to construct a network request.

Comment: Never mind, sounds like I can use `CustomizeDiff: func f(_ context.Context, diff *schema.ResourceDiff, meta interface{}) error` signature

Comment: It seems like there's no `d.Set()` for `schema.ResourceDiff` and `d.SetNew()` only operate on computed keys. E.g., when I try to use `d.SetNew` as `d.Set()` I'm getting `SetNew only operates on computed keys - xyz is not one`. Is there a workaround?

Comment: when I add `Computed: True` I'm getting `xyz: Cannot be both Required and Computed`

Comment: Sounds like I might have to set Optional: True, Computed: True and then add an extra check to require `xyz` attribute to fake `Required: True`.

Comment: I think what you're asking here might be better as a separate question because I sense that there's something going on here that I'm not fully appreciating just from these small snippets. `Required` though means that the module author _must_ set it, which means that in turn your provider _must_ preserve exactly what they set when responding. `Optional`+`Computed` together means that the author _may_ set it but if they don't set it then the provider can insert a default value instead of `null`. I think you might be trying to do something outside of the "rules" I described, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I'm not sure, I feel like it very much relates to your answer. More specifically, you wrote "you would call d.Set with the value from the prior state -- the "old" value.". However there's no Set() for schema.ResourceDiff and only SetNew() is available but it can only be called for a computed attributes -- otherwise it returns "SetNew only operates on computed keys - xyz is not one" error (xyz is the name of the attribute). However xyz attribute has `Required: True` so when I add `Computed: True` I get another TF error: xyz: Cannot be both Required and Computed - hence Optional + Computed.

Comment: added https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319865/where-do-old-new-d-getchange-come-from-in-customizediff-and-diffsuppressfun

Comment: You are right that I should've said `SetNew` instead of `Set` here. I was thinking of the similar `ResourceData` method, but `ResourceDiff` has a stronger distinction between the "old" and "new" because it's representing a change, and so the method names have additional suffixes to represent that. I'll update my answer to use that method name instead.