# Where do old,new := d.GetChange() come from in CustomizeDiff and DiffSuppressFunc?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

There're 2 methods:

- [CustomizeDiff](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/resources/customizing-differences)
- [DiffSuppressFunc](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/sdkv2/schemas/schema-behaviors)

Corresponding objects (schema.ResourceDiff and schema.Resource) support `old, new := d.GetChange("foo")`, however I'm confused about where these values are coming from.

I've been thinking that

```
DiffSuppressFunc: func(k, old, new string, d *schema.ResourceData) bool
```

taked `old` from TF state and `new` from the result from running readResource(). What if there's 0 diff and then user changes `main.tf` -- is it `old` or `new` value?

and for `CustomizeDiff`:

```
old, new := d.GetChange("foo")
```

it seems like `new` is from TF state / main.tf but `old` is from `readResource()`.

Where can I read about it more? I was always thinking that TF state is `old` and then response is `new` -- when looking at output from TF drift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DiffSuppressFunc` abstraction in this old Terraform SDK is unfortunately one of the parts that still retains some outdated assumptions from older versions of Terraform, since it was those older versions that this SDK was originally designed to serve.

Specifically, in Terraform v0.11 and earlier the model of resource state and plan data was a flat map from strings to strings and the SDK internally translated between that and the heirarchical structures described in the schema. Under this model, a list in the provider schema serializes as a bunch of separate entries in the flat map, like `example.#` giving the number of elements, `example.0` giving the first element, etc.

`DiffSuppressFunc` is one place where that internal implementation detail leaked up into the API, because "diff suppressing" is an operation done against the already-flattened data structure that's describing the changes, and so the schema type information has all been lost.

You shouldn't typically need to worry about exactly what `old` and `new` mean because the purpose of `DiffSuppressFunc` is only to determine whether the two values are functionally equivalent. The function only needs to compare the two and return `true` if they represent alternative serializations of the same information.

However, if you're curious about the implementation details then you can review [the part of the SDK which calls this function](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/blob/649a3f2d5519ef5016320df558c0597b13c41d61/helper/schema/schema.go#L1140-L1158).

---

`CustomizeDiff`'s behavior is more specialized than `DiffSuppressFunc`, because it's used for one purpose and one purpose only: adding special behaviors to run during Terraform's "plan" step.

In this case then the old value is always the most recent known value for a particular argument, and the new value starts off being a value from the current configuration but you can override it using `SetNew` or `SetNewComputed` methods of `ResourceDiff`.

To emulate what might normally be done by a `CustomizeDiff` you'd write logic something like this:

```
old, new := d.GetChange("foo")
if functionallyEquivalent(old, new) {
    d.SetNew(old)
}
```

The definition of `functionallyEquivalent` is for you to write based on your knowledge of the system which you are wrapping with this provider. If `foo` is a string attribute then you can use type assertions like `old.(string)` and `new.(string)` to get the actual string values to compare.

---

SDKv2 is essentially a legacy system at this point, designed around the behaviors of an obsolete version of Terraform. It's still available primarily to support existing providers which were themselves originally written for those obsolete versions of Terraform.

The new [Terraform Plugin Framework](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework) is built for modern Terraform and so has fewer "gotchas" resulting from inconsistencies between how the SDK works and how Terraform itself works.

The modern equivalent of `CustomizeDiff` in the plugin framework is [plan modification](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/plugin/framework/resources/plan-modification), and a plan modifier for a string attribute would be an implementation of [`planmodifier.String`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/resource/schema/planmodifier#String).

The new API makes it a bit more explicit where all of these values are coming from: the [`StringRequest`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-framework/resource/schema/planmodifier#StringRequest) type differentiates between the value from the configuration, the value from the prior state, and the value from the *proposed* new state, which is the framework's initial attempt to construct a plan prior to any custom modifications in the provider.

Therefore a plan modifier for normalizing a string attribute in a similar manner to `DiffSuppressFunc` in the old SDK would be:

```
func (m ExampleStringModifier) PlanModifyString(ctx context.Context, req StringRequest, resp *StringResponse) {
    if functionallyEquivalent(req.StateValue, req.PlanValue) {
        // Preserve the value from the prior state if the
        // new value is equivalent to it.
        resp.PlanValue = req.StateValue
    }
}
```

Again you'll need to define and implement the exact rule for what `functionallyEquivalent` means for this particular attribute.

Comment: Does your answer imply that a user should only use CustomizeDiff and not DiffSuppressFunc?

Comment: If `DiffSuppressFunc` is sufficient for whatever the goal is then I don't think there's anything wrong with using it. It's typically easier to implement for the common case of just neutralizing some normalization the API might do, such as considering two JSON strings equal if they differ only in unimportant whitespace between tokens.

Comment: However, if `DiffSuppressFunc`'s limitations make it hard to use it in a particular situation -- for example, if what you want to normalize is a map or list of strings instead of just a string -- then `CustomizeDiff` is a plausible alternative.

Comment: `SetNew` doesnt work inside `CustomizeDiff` for `TypeList`  fields. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-plugin-sdk/issues/459

Comment: Indeed, if you want to modify the diff for part of a list then you would need to retrieve the entire list, modify it, and then write the entire list back again.

Comment: that too only on computed fields :/